# how to send http request without urlencode?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib, urlencode

I am doing a Scan work，and Need to send http requests without urlencode. The web application use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'](php) to get URL, and I must use "<" or ">" to do my scan work. But python requests will encode ">" to "%3E". Is there any way to send http request without urlencode(requests, urllib, urllib2), except sending http requests using socket?

Firstly, I use requests to do it:

`import requests
requests.get("http://test.com/index.php?id=1 and 1>1")`

But the truth url the requests get is： http://test.com/index.php?id=1 and 1%3E1

This question has confused me for days, I'll be very happy to get any solution from you, and thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `string` parameters using the `params` argument. Like this:

```
requests.get("http://test.com/index.php", params="id=1 and 1>1")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: Sorry, I tried this way, But in burpsuite it's still http://test.com/index.php?id=1%20and%201%3E1"